# Using PHP and xPath to store value as per label text?

Tags: php, xpath

I am trying to store text/string values. The values do not have a unique identifier. However a unique label exists.

**Using xPath and PHP, how can the value be stored?**

I secondary problem is that the Sector label contains none, one or many results depending on record

Example:

```
[Location] = London, UK;
[Price] = £5000;
[Sector] = IT, ICT;
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="DetailsPanel">
        <label class="ListLabel left">Location</label>
        <span id="location" class="ListDetail left" title="London, UK">London, UK</span>
         <label class="ListLabel left">Price</label>
        <span id="price" class="ListDetail left" title="£5000">£5000</span>
        <label class="ListLabel left">Sector</label>
        <span class="ListDetail left">
          <a href="/">IT</a>
          <a href="/">ICT</a>
        </span>
      </div>
```

Current Code:

```
 foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    $node = $xpath->query("div/a | div/p | div/label | div/span", $entry);

    echo '<job>' . "\n";

    foreach ($node as $i) {
        $tag = $i->nodeName;
        $att = $i->getAttribute('id');
        $string = $i->nodeValue;
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+\s+/','',$string);

....

 echo '<' . $tag . ">" . $string . '</' . $tag . ">" . "\n";
```

Comment: Why are you particular looking for an XPath solution? Do you have some existing PHP code you can show us? There may be a more appropriate answer involving HTML parsing tools, rather than re-purposed XML ones.

Comment: Doesn't need to be xPath however this is what I have been using.

Answer (score 1):

PHP isn't my main language, but here's a quick approach getting the labels first and then getting the adjacent span elements using xpath:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<div class="DetailsPanel">
    <label class="ListLabel left">Location</label>
    <span id="location" class="ListDetail left" title="London, UK">London, UK</span>
     <label class="ListLabel left">Price</label>
    <span id="price" class="ListDetail left" title="£5000">£5000</span>
    <label class="ListLabel left">Sector</label>
    <span class="ListDetail left">
      <a href="/">IT</a>
      <a href="/">ICT</a>
    </span>
  </div>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

/* get label nodes*/
$label = $xml->xpath('label');

/* iterate over labels */
foreach ($label as $l) {

    /* get adjacent span element */
    foreach ($l->xpath("following-sibling::span[1]") as $span) {        
        $a = "";
        /* if span has a */
        if ($span->xpath("a")) {
            $a = join(", ",$span->xpath("a"));
        }          
    }
    echo $l, " : ", $span,$a, "<br/>";
}
?>
```

This will echo out:

```
Location : London, UK
Price : £5000
Sector : IT, ICT
```